# Inconclusive Error with No reference or Unable to find Reference causing - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I get a following error in my crash list and i have not idea on how to link it with my code, as it looks generic and inconclusive

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 

  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException (ArrayList.java:255)

  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:308)

  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem (ArrayAdapter.java:337)

  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (ArrayAdapter.java:390)

  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView (ArrayAdapter.java:362)

  at android.widget.Spinner.makeView (Spinner.java:661)

  at android.widget.Spinner.layout (Spinner.java:609)

  at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout (Spinner.java:568)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal (LinearLayout.java:1692)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1468)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)

  at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout (ScrollView.java:1511)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout (ViewPager.java:1795)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1077)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1703)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1557)

  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1466)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:579)

  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:514)

  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:16075)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5300)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2119)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1873)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1073)

  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:5988)

  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:767)

  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:580)

  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:550)

  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:753)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5930)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1405)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

I am new to android programming, any help on how to fix this issue is greatly appreciated.

Becos everyone is asking the adapter code i will post One sample adapter here,

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int REP_TYPE = 1;
    public static final int ME_TYPE = 2;
    public static final int FILE_TYPE = 4;
    public static final int FILE_DONE = 5;
    public static final int FILE_DONE_REP = 6;
    public static final int FOOTER_TYPE = 3;

    List<Message> messages;
    String rep_photo;
    String me_photo;

    Context context;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, String rep_photo, String me_photo) {
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
        this.rep_photo = rep_photo;
        this.me_photo = me_photo;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messageList){
        messages = messageList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addMessage(Message message){
        messages.add(0, message);
        notifyItemInserted(0);
    }

    public void addMessageList(List<Message> messageList){
        int size = this.messages.size();
        this.messages.remove(size -1);
        notifyItemRemoved(size - 1);
        size = this.messages.size();
        this.messages.addAll(messageList);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(size, messageList.size());
    }

    public void replaceFileMessage(){
        int position = 0;
        for (Message message1 : messages){
            if (message1.msg.contains("::FILE::")){
                position = messages.indexOf(message1);
                messages.remove(position);
                break;
            }
        }
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case FILE_TYPE: return new FileHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_me_chat_file, parent, false));
            case FILE_DONE: return new FileDoneHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_me_chat_file_done, parent, false));
            case FILE_DONE_REP: return new FileDoneRepHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rep_chat_file_done, parent, false));
            case FOOTER_TYPE: return new FooterHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer_user_list, parent, false));
            case ME_TYPE: return new MeHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_me_msg, parent, false));
            default: return new RepHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rep_message, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if (holder instanceof MeHolder){
            MeHolder meHolder = (MeHolder) holder;
            meHolder.bind(message);
        }else if (holder instanceof RepHolder){
            RepHolder repHolder = (RepHolder) holder;
            repHolder.bind(message);
        }else if (holder instanceof FileHolder){
            FileHolder fileHolder = (FileHolder) holder;
            fileHolder.bind(message);
        }else if (holder instanceof FileDoneHolder){
            FileDoneHolder fileDoneHolder = (FileDoneHolder) holder;
            fileDoneHolder.bind(message);
        }else if (holder instanceof FileDoneRepHolder){
            FileDoneRepHolder fileDoneRepHolder = (FileDoneRepHolder) holder;
            fileDoneRepHolder.bind(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (messages.size() > 0 && messages.size() > 25 &&
                position == messages.size() - 1 && messages.get(position) == null){
            return FOOTER_TYPE;
        }else {
            Message message = messages.get(position);
            if (message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE::")) {
                return FILE_TYPE;
            }else if (message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE_DONE::")) {
                return FILE_DONE;
            }else if (message.to_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE_DONE::")) {
                return FILE_DONE_REP;
            }else if(message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id)){
                return ME_TYPE;
            } else {
                return REP_TYPE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    class RepHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements Html.ImageGetter{

        @BindView(R.id.ivUser)
        CircleImageView ivUser;

        @BindView(R.id.tvMsg)
        BlackTextView tvMsg;

        @BindView(R.id.tvTime)
        BlackTextView tvTime;

        public RepHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(final Message message){
            for(String s : ChatActivity.smilesMapReplaces.keySet()){
                if (message.msg.contains(s)){
                    String img = "<img src='" + s + "' />";
                    if (s.equals(":)")){
                        s = ":\\)";
                    }else if(s.equals(":(")){
                        s = ":\\(";
                    }else if(s.equals(";)")){
                        s = ";\\)";
                    }
                    message.msg = message.msg.replaceAll(s, img);
                }
            }
            tvMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.msg, this, null));
            Picasso.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(rep_photo).into(ivUser);
            tvTime.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayTime(tvTime.getContext(), message.created, DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601));
            ivUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((BaseActivity)ivUser.getContext()).startActivity(ProfileActivity.class, AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id.equals(message.from_user) ? message.to_user : message.from_user, false);
                }
            });
            if (message.msg.startsWith("http")){
                tvMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(message.msg));
                        tvMsg.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            if (source.contains("http")) {
                LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
                Drawable empty = tvMsg.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
                d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
                d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

                new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

                return d;
            }else{
                int id = ChatActivity.smilesMapReplaces.get(source);
                Drawable d = tvMsg.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);
                d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth() * 3/2,d.getIntrinsicHeight() * 3/2);
                return d;
            }
        }

        class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

            private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
                String source = (String) params[0];
                mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
                try {
                    InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
                    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth()*3, bitmap.getHeight()*3);
                    mDrawable.setLevel(1);
                    // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
                    // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
                    CharSequence t = tvMsg.getText();
                    tvMsg.setText(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class FileHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.tvName)
        BlackTextView tvName;

        @BindView(R.id.tvTime)
        BlackTextView tvTime;

        @BindView(R.id.ivUser)
        ImageView ivUser;

        public FileHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(Message message){
            String fileName = message.msg.substring(8, message.msg.length());
            tvName.setText(fileName);
            Picasso.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(me_photo).into(ivUser);
            tvTime.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayTime(tvTime.getContext(), message.created, DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601));
        }
    }

    class FileDoneHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.tvName)
        BlackTextView tvName;

        @BindView(R.id.tvTime)
        BlackTextView tvTime;

        @BindView(R.id.ivUser)
        ImageView ivUser;

        @BindView(R.id.ivFile)
        ImageView ivFile;

        @BindView(R.id.ivAttachment)
        ImageView ivAttachment;

        public FileDoneHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(Message message){
            final String fileName = message.msg.substring(13, message.msg.length());
            tvName.setText(fileName);
            Picasso.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(me_photo).into(ivUser);
            tvTime.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayTime(tvTime.getContext(), message.created, DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601));
            tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/");
                    if (!fileDir.exists()){
                        fileDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/" + fileName);
                    if (file.exists()){
                        UIUtils.openFile(context, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }else{
                        new DownloadFileFromURL(fileName).execute(Constants.BASE_FILE_URL + fileName);
                    }
                }
            });
            ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/");
                    if (!fileDir.exists()){
                        fileDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/" + fileName);
                    if (file.exists()){
                        UIUtils.openFile(context, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }else{
                        new DownloadFileFromURL(fileName).execute(Constants.BASE_FILE_URL + fileName);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class FileDoneRepHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.tvName)
        BlackTextView tvName;

        @BindView(R.id.tvTime)
        BlackTextView tvTime;

        @BindView(R.id.ivUser)
        ImageView ivUser;

        @BindView(R.id.ivAttachment)
        ImageView ivAttachment;

        public FileDoneRepHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(Message message){
            final String fileName = message.msg.substring(13, message.msg.length());
            tvName.setText(fileName);
            Picasso.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(rep_photo).into(ivUser);
            tvTime.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayTime(tvTime.getContext(), message.created, DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601));
            ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/");
                    if (!fileDir.exists()){
                        fileDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/" + fileName);
                    if (file.exists()){
                        UIUtils.openFile(context, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }else{
                        new DownloadFileFromURL(fileName).execute(Constants.BASE_FILE_URL + fileName);
                    }
                }
            });
            tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/");
                    if (!fileDir.exists()){
                        fileDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/" + fileName);
                    if (file.exists()){
                        UIUtils.openFile(context, file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }else{
                        new DownloadFileFromURL(fileName).execute(Constants.BASE_FILE_URL + fileName);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class MeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements Html.ImageGetter{
        @BindView(R.id.ivUser)
        CircleImageView ivUser;

        @BindView(R.id.tvMsg)
        BlackTextView tvMsg;

        @BindView(R.id.tvTime)
        BlackTextView tvTime;

        public MeHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(final Message message){
            for(String s : ChatActivity.smilesMapReplaces.keySet()){

                if (message.msg.contains(s)){
                    String img = "<img src='" + s + "' />";
                    if (s.equals(":)")){
                        s = ":\\)";
                    }else if(s.equals(":(")){
                        s = ":\\(";
                    }else if(s.equals(";)")){
                        s = ";\\)";
                    }
                    message.msg = message.msg.replaceAll(s, img);
                }
            }
            tvMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.msg, this, null));
            Picasso.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(me_photo).into(ivUser);
            ivUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((BaseActivity)ivUser.getContext()).startActivity(ProfileActivity.class, AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id, false);
                }
            });
            if (message.msg.startsWith("http")){
                tvMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(message.msg));
                        tvMsg.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });
            }
            tvTime.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayTime(tvTime.getContext(), message.created, DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_ISO_8601));
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            if (source.contains("http")) {
                LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
                Drawable empty = tvMsg.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
                d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
                d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

                new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

                return d;
            }else{
                int id = ChatActivity.smilesMapReplaces.get(source);
                Drawable d = tvMsg.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);
                d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth() * 3/2,d.getIntrinsicHeight() * 3/2);
                return d;
            }
        }

        class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

            private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
                String source = (String) params[0];
                mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
                try {
                    InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
                    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth()*3, bitmap.getHeight()*3);
                    mDrawable.setLevel(1);
                    // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
                    // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
                    CharSequence t = tvMsg.getText();
                    tvMsg.setText(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class FooterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public FooterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String fileName;
        public DownloadFileFromURL(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/araliya/" + fileName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return  null;
            }

            return fileName;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (file_url != null){
                UIUtils.openFile(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/araliya/" + file_url);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Best guess is that you've modified the `List` backing your `Adapter` without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so the adapter thinks it has more items than it actually does. Could you post all adapter-related code you have?

Comment: @BenP. There is about 30+ adapters in use throughout the project how am i suppose to know where it is calling this.

Comment: You really need to post your code. Without it, we really can't help much.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai as i said really impossible to test and post 50+ adapter code used in the app, as i dont even know which area it crashes.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to help you. But the stacktrace very clearly says that the index out of bounds exception happens in `ArrayList.java` class on line 255

Comment: You are showing an RecyerView.Adapter, but your error is at some ArrayAdapter, you need to find the one

Comment: Debug your code or add logging, so you know what adapter was executing with what data.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker  as i said really impossible to test and post 50+ adapter code used in the app, as i dont even know which area it crashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this exception:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
> at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException (ArrayList.java:255)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:308)

and this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (messages.size() > 0 && messages.size() > 25 &&
        position == messages.size() - 1 && messages.get(position) == null){
        return FOOTER_TYPE;
    }else {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if (message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE::")) {
            return FILE_TYPE;
        }else if (message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE_DONE::")) {
            return FILE_DONE;
        }else if (message.to_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id) && message.msg.contains("::FILE_DONE::")) {
            return FILE_DONE_REP;
        }else if(message.from_user.equals(AppSetting.getInstance().getUserData().user_id)){
            return ME_TYPE;
        } else {
            return REP_TYPE;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the following lines might be the cause of the problem:

```
if (messages.size() > 0 && messages.size() > 25 && position == messages.size() - 1 && messages.get(position) == null) {...}
else {
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    ...
}
```

When you do: *messages.get(position)* it throws **IndexOutOfBoundsException** if the index is out of range. So, what do you think will happen if position is 29 but messages.size() is 27? And any idea regarding this check **messages.size() > 0 && messages.size() > 25** in your **if block**? I think that you should focus on `messages list and position value`. To avoid exception on `messages.get(position)` operation the value of `position` should follow this rule: ***-1 < position < messages.size()***.

**Additional Info:**

From [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)), method ***int getItemViewType(int position)***:

> Get the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup) for the specified item.
>
> Parameter: position - int: The position of the item within the adapter's data set whose view type we want.
>
> Returns - An integer representing the type of View. Two views should share the same type if one can be converted to the other in getView(int, View, ViewGroup). Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1. IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE can also be returned.

So, the reason is that **`position`** of the item within the adapter's data set does not correspond to the position of item in **`List<Message> messages`**.

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading! The ``Message message = messages.get(position);`` cannot be the reason, because if it were the reason it then would be listed in the stacktrace. The suggested code change at the end is also wrong. Method ``notifyItemRangeInserted()`` expects the number of inserted items as second argument. The original code is correct. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int)

Comment: @Boomer thanks for your response! Agree with notifyItemRangeInserted(), it's my fault, edited, sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   (ArrayList.java:255)

[**`IndexOutOfBoundsException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is an unchecked exception that extends [**`RuntimeException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) .

**REASON**

> This exception can be thrown to indicate an attempt to access an index
>   which is out of bounds on objects like String, Array, or Vector.
>   Usually any negative integer less than or equal to -1 and positive
>   integer greater than or equal to the size of the object is an index
>   which would be out of bounds.

**Handling**

The process of handling the exception thrown by the Java Runtime Environment, while the program is being executed, is known as exception handling. use [**`try-catch()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) block.

```
try  
    {
      // Your CODE

    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException  exp)  // Exception
    {
      System.out.println("Exception "  + exp.getMessage() );
    }
```

> If I can't find-out when this breaks it's really impossible to debug as
>   i have large app with over 50+ adapters calling in different different
>   actions.

It will be better if you [**`Debugging`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) App. It's a good practice.

**WHY ?**

**Debugging** allows you to go through each line of code, methods and how well your code is working. It’s **`easier to find small mistake in large pieces of code`**.

**Coming from**

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (messages.size() > 0 && messages.size() > 25 &&
                position == messages.size() - 1 && messages.get(position) == null){
            return FOOTER_TYPE;
        }
```

Debug **`if`** section. Check every conditions properly satisfied or not. Specially **`messages.size()`**.

Comment: I understand this needs a try catch block however my question is more of how to find what action it causes this exception because there is over 1000+ active users and only 1 person is having this issue, plus all the adapters and testing seems to be fine, i think there is one particular rare case which causes this issue, however its impossible to replicate this error or debug as you guys saying its not just a simple app with simple logic.

Comment: @mahen3d I understand your problem. It will be helpful if you share your code. App DEBUGGING is the best approach to find problem as far as i know.

Comment: @mahen3d You can visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/21570366/3395198 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014513/java-util-arraylist-throwindexoutofboundsexceptionarraylist-java255-error

Answer (score 2):

I think that is due to out of memory. Sometimes android create unknown error like this when there is **OOM** error. It must be for user with low memory remaining on device.

**Profile your app.**
Android 3.0 introduce great feature for profiling app, so use that.

**Find memory leaks**
Finding memory leak can help you to build bug free applications. Even if you know your app is good with memory management, you should cgeck for it.

**Manage memory**
Find out some memory management tips for android and use it.

**Best practices **
Try googling for best practices for android development. This will help you lot to solve your problem.